# How do I print each individual property of an object when that object itself is stored in an array index in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm new to programming and trying to create a blog from scratch to not only work on my coding skills but also this blog will document my learning process.

Instead of hard coding each new post to the index.html page I want to create a type of admin page that has two `input` fields of `type="text"`, one for the title of the post and the other for the content of the post. My submit button will take my user input from those fields and store them in an object that is my `makePost` constructor function which in turn, each object will be stored in an array called `posts`.

I then want to iterate through the array and print out each object's individual properties for each post...each property being `title`, `date`, `content`. So far I am able to create an object with these three properties and store it in the zero-index of my array (`array[0]`) but when I print out the object using my for-loop to iterate through my array it prints the entire object... I think I need to access each of those properties in my for-loop?

Also I realize in this code block I'm printing to the console but I just did that to make sure something was working. At the end of the code I posted what it's printing out in the console. Now I just need to break down each property in that object and print them out in their respective HTML tags.

I've been searching for days before I decided to post and I can't find anything that is specific to exactly what I'm trying to do using JavaScript. Thank you in advance for your help.

Here's my code so far:

```js
document.getElementById('button').onclick = function() {
  var title = document.getElementById('title').value;
  var content = document.getElementById('content').value;
  var posts = [];
  var makePost = function(title, content) {
    return {
      title: title,
      date: Date(),
      content: content
    }
  }
  posts.unshift(makePost(title, content));
  for (var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
    var myPost = posts[i];
    console.log(myPost);
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
form {
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
h3 {
  margin: 10px;
}
#title {
  margin: 10px;
}
#date {
  margin: 10px;
}
#content {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<h3>Type the content that you would like to show in the post section of the blog</h3>
<form class="form" action="index.html" method="post">
  Title:<input id="title" type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="Type title here"><br />
  <!-- Date:<input id="date" type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="Type date here"><br /> -->
  Content:<input id="content" type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="Type content here">
  <input id="button" type="button" name="name" value="Submit">
</form>
<h2 id="displaytitle">This is the title of the post</h2>
<h2 id="displaydate">This is the date of the post</h2>
<h2 id="displaycontent">This is the content of the post</h2>
```

Here is what it prints to the console:

```
Object {title: "This is my title", date: "Fri Feb 19 2016 09:54:37 GMT-0800 (PST)", content: "This is my content"}
```

Comment: You're basically just asking how a [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop works ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To iterate over your array and print out your well known attributes use this:

```
posts.forEach(function(post) {
    console.log("Title: " + post.title);
    console.log("\tDate: " + post.date);
    console.log("\tContent: " + post.content);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
    var myPost = posts[i];
    for(var key in myPost) {
          console.log(myPost[key]);
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var k in target){
 if (target.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
     alert("Key is " + k + ", value is" + target[k]);
 }
}
```